# Sending a RESTful url (endpoint) from Band

Tags: microsoft-band

I just have a general question. Can you send a url from a button on the band. I have a home automation system that you can trigger events by sending a RESTful url (endpoint) to. Basically I can put the url in any web browser and trigger the event. It would be great if this could be done through the Band. I don't really need a response from the Url, just to send it.

Does that make sense?
Thanks,
Scott

Answer (score 0):

No, the Band communicates only via Bluetooth to (applications on) its paired device.  On Windows (Phone), the application must be running, with a connection to the Band, and subscribed to the Tile button pressed event in order to receive such notifications.  This generally rules out scenarios that require ad-hoc input from the Band unless you're willing to use voice commands via Cortana.

Comment: Thanks, but couldnt you just have a button on the band which when pressed had the phone send the url? I would not need any feedback from the url on the phone or the band, just that the url was sent.

Comment: A challenge of the mobile platforms (e.g. Windows Phone) is that their sandboxing of applications (for security reasons) means that it can be difficult for applications to coordinate their activity.  For example, for the Microsoft Health application which generally receives ad-hoc input from the Band to notify the application which actually added the Tile that a button has been pressed.  In your scenario, the Band would likely have to store the URL itself, which likely means changes to the Band firmware, SDK, and Health application.  That's a lot of change for this very specific scenario.

Answer (score 0):

But i think its possible by creating custom tile and handling custom tile events. Haven't tried it in my project but can see from sdk documentation.
For android you can implement broadcast receiver and listen to tile events. Check: [sdk doc](https://developer.microsoftband.com/Content/docs/Microsoft%20Band%20SDK.pdf)
Chap 9, page 51

Answer (score 0):

In short, yes it is possible.

However, the problem would be that the button would be single use to only send that ONE URL command and it actually wouldn't be done via the Band.

You can create custom layouts for your applications with the Microsoft Band SDK which will allow you to create a button. You'll then need to register to the click event from the Band which then would get fired on the device the app is running on. From there, you'd be able to send the URL but it would be sent from the Windows Phone or Windows PC rather than the Band so you'd need to be connected. The documentation covers how you can do this here: http://developer.microsoftband.com/Content/docs/Microsoft%20Band%20SDK.pdf

A downside to doing this with WinRT is that as soon as the app is closed and the connection to the Band is lost, your button click won't have any action. The best way to get around this is to create the connection to the Band in a background task but unfortunately, you can't keep hold of the connection to the Band for an infinite amount of time and you'd have to live with the possibilities that you may have times where it doesn't work. I have a [GitHub sample](https://github.com/jamesmcroft/MicrosoftBand-BackgroundSample) which shows you how to connect to the Band in a background task for an indefinite amount of time.

The Microsoft Band has really been developed for the Health aspect and collecting data rather than interactions with other apps which it does in some way support.